# Marginal tax rate question

Tags: taxation, marginal

> In relation to an ordinary employee, the Prime Minister of Australia pays?
>
> a) the same marginal tax rate
>
> b) a higher marginal tax ate
>
> c) a lower marginal tax rate

My answer for this was a), as it was explained to me that 'marginal tax rates' refers to the tables that are used to calculate tax, but others are debating whether it is b), as the Prime Minister typically falls under a higher tax bracket than others. Would someone care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

The Prime Minister of Australia seems to earn around AUD $500,000 [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Australia#Salary)

This would give him a marginal tax rate of [45%](https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/) plus supplements

The [average for full-time employees](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/mf/6302.0) seems to be close to AUD $80,000 which would make typical marginal rates either [32.5% or 37%](https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/)

So the Prime Minister of Australia pays a higher marginal tax ate